# use multi entity in form builder in symfony2

Tags: symfony, entity

i want to use more than one entity to create form in createformbuilder .
forexample i want to have a form with many fields from many entity 
and i want to check condition for view fields

```
userEntity -> email , password 
resselerEntity - > (userEntity fields) + managerName , managerFamily
leaderEntity - > (userEntity fields) + credit
```

and if i want to show resseler fields , must show all fields of `userEntity` and `resselerEntity`

if want to show `userEntity` , must show all fields of `userEntity`

and etc,

so how can i solve this solution ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Most common solution is to create single forms for (in your case):

- userEntity
- ressellerEntity

Then, create a new form that have two fields of userEntityFormType and ressellerEntityFormType.

In that way you can:

- Separate your constraints
- Use elsewhere single form

Something like that

```
class UserEntityType extends AbstractType
{
 public function BuildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
  $builder->add('firstField')
          ->add('secondField')
          [...]
          ->lastField;
 }

 public function getName()
 {
  return 'UserEntityType ';
 }
}


class RessellerEntityType extends AbstractType
{
 public function BuildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
  $builder->add('firstField')
          ->add('secondField')
          [...]
          ->lastField;
 }

 public function getName()
 {
  return 'RessellersEntityType ';
 }
}



class AggregateEntityType extends AbstractType
    {
     public function BuildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
     {
      $builder->add('userEntityField',UserEntityType,array('multiple'=>true)
              ->add('ressellersEntityField',RessellersEntityType,array('multiple'=>true));
     }

     public function getName()
     {
      return 'AggregateEntityType ';
     }
    }
```

Comment: yes i want to create single form but that must included more than one entity. if i create signle form for each entity and if i want to modify name of common entity filds later , i must modify all fields and it's not correct !!

Comment: @hamid: no, if you specify that fields of the third entity is multiple, take a look at my update

Comment: so how can i check condition ?
if i want to show resseller fields show user and resseller entity !
if i want to show leader fields show user and leader entity !
if i want to show user filds show user entity !

Comment: @hamid: with condition, you mean "constraints" ?

Comment: @hamid your question isn't clear. Please, update it with some examples. Than you.

Comment: for example if i want to show resseller form 
i must show all resseller field and show all user fields

and if i want to show leader form
i must show all leader fields and name , family fields in user entity


i said how can i check that ?
if i want show leader form , dont show all fields of user

Comment: @hamid: sorry, to me this isn't clear at all. Please, wait for someone can understand better and so, help you

Answer (score 0):

I think Don got you most of the way there.  Add a construct argument to your UserType

```
public function __construct($otherEntityType) // Reseller, Leader etc.
```

Then use otherEntityType to determine which fields are created for UserType.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you should use type inheritance:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('password')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => '\Hamid\User',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'hamid_user';
    }
}

class ResellerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('managerName')
            ->add('managerFamily')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => '\Hamid\Reseller',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'hamid_reseller';
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'hamid_user';
    }
}
```

Then use the right form for each entity. If, for whatever reason, you need a single form that adapts to the class of the entity set to the form, you need to use form events, as [explained in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).